# How does mentioned output get? please explain the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

```py
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(1, 6):
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i]
for i in range(0, 6): 
    print(arr[i], end = " ")
```

Answer is :2 3 4 5 6 6

Comment: Could you clarify what the issue is? Are you asking why the code snippet produces that output?

Comment: Can you please explain -- > arr[i - 1] = arr[i]  this line how it process? and this --> print(arr[i], end = " ")

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(1, 6):
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i]
for i in range(0, 6): 
    print(arr[i], end = " ")
```

arr is a list comprised of 6 integers.

In your first *for* loop, *i* will vary from 1 to 5 (inclusive).

Python lists are accessed using base-0 - i.e., the first element is at index zero, the second at 1 and so on.

Therefore your loop is moving every element to the position (index) that immediately precedes it. Nothing is moved into index 5

Answer (score 0):

if you are refering to get the following result : 2 3 4 5 6 1
then you should rearrange the following way:

```
for i in range(0, 6):
     arr[i-1] = arr[i]
```

that way, you start with arr[-1] = arr[0], so 6 will be replaced with 1 and so the code goes on